# iphone - is it ok to use usleep on a secondary thread on Grand Central Dispatch?

Tags: iphone, grand-central-dispatch

I am adding a block to a queue (not the main queue), using Grand Central Dispatch. This block has a loop and between every passage of the loop a small delay of 0,02 seconds is required. I am using

```
dispatch_async(myOwnQueue, ^{
  // begin loop
  // do stuff
  usleep(20000);
  // end loop
});
```

on this queue. As it is not the main queue, it will not block the main thread.

The problem is that Xcode complains: **warning: implicit declaration of function 'usleep'**

Is there other way to do that?

thanks.

Comment: Won't dispatch_after be a better solution?

Comment: Yeah, busy-waiting is not the answer. Use dispatch_after or an NSTimer, or a dispatch_source timer, but don't busy-wait on GCD threads. GCD works best when the work items you submit to it don't block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to include the appropriate header before calling usleep():

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh I love SO and all experts it joins!!! thanks!