# Is there any reason to not use sleep in a Grand Central Dispatch queue?

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I would like to make a queue wait for a short period while it is looping. I am considering my options and was testing out suspending a resuming a queue but that seems to require several moving parts. So I am considering using sleep or usleep instead. That is more of a general threading function and would like to know if I should avoid using sleep and instead stick with GCD options to make a queue pause.

I found one related question but that answer shows that he was just missing an include. Are there any concerns with mixing sleep calls in with GCD queues?

[iphone - is it ok to use usleep on a secondary thread on Grand Central Dispatch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668634/iphone-is-it-ok-to-use-usleep-on-a-secondary-thread-on-grand-central-dispatch)

Comment: I usually consider sleep loops an indicator of a design that needs rethinking. Is there any reason why you cannot get threads to notify each other when things are ready to go rather than polling?

Comment: @Derek - It may not be polling, but something that happens every 50ms, for example, that is my assumption at least, but, good question. :)

Comment: @James Black: Isn't `dispatch_after` (and friends) more suited to solving that problem?

Comment: In this case I am using AVAssetReader and I want to read in only a few seconds worth of audio at at time and then pause reading while the audio that is loaded is playing. (unfortunately I cannot precisely load just small portions at a time with separate calls) When it resumes it will check if it needs to continue loading more data yet. Another option is to use pthreads with a mutex but that is also more moving parts when sleep appears to do the job. I can load 5 seconds worth of audio and have it delay a second at a time to keep ahead of the play time.

Comment: Why are you trying to throttle your asset reader manually?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @NSReponder I cannot load an entire song from the iPod library into memory. I am processing the audio through an Audio Unit callback to play live so I stagger reading to bring in a little at a time. I would like a better way to do this if there is a better way to go. There is little documentation on some of the new APIs that I am using. Any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use sleep, but as you mentioned, do it off of the main thread, as you should never tie up the main thread.

But, if you need a small sleep, the amount of time may not be precise, and is unlikely to be, but the thread will be woken up at least after the amount of sleep, depending on what else may be using the cpu.

But, I see no problem with using sleep as it will at least give other threads/applications, a chance to run.

Comment: Thanks, I am keeping all this work on a queue which is running async. I run queues on the main thread when necessary. It can still get a little tricky with passing variables around, especially the AudioBufferList which I need to collect many instances and it's a struct so managing that collection will be done without Objective-C objects since I am processing the audio with an Audio Unit callback. Now I have to figure out how I will hold onto all those ABL instances and release them safely.

Comment: Sometimes I tie up the main thread for a moment, for example NSOutlineView has nice animation when you expand the children of an item, but if you fetch the children on a background thread (after the user expands it) then there won't be any animation. So I trigger the background thread, then block the main thread for an instant, then if the background thread has already finished I'll return the items NSOutlineView has asked for, and it'll do it's animation. If the thread is still going I return some kind of "..." value and tell it to reload when the background is done.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert - I would look for a different solution, as tying up the UI thread may cause grief for the user, as they are trying to do something but no response.

Answer (score 10):

Since this has issue caused me a lot of grief over the years, I figured I'd share the benefit of that <strike>suffering</strike> experience:

Any time you block (which includes calling `sleep`) in a work unit* submitted to GCD, you are creating a situation with the potential for thread starvation. Worse yet, if your work unit's blocking is due to the use of synchronization primitives (i.e. semaphores, locks, etc), or if multiple work units are interlocked using these primitives, thread starvation has the potential to cause deadlocks. More in a minute, but here's the short version:

> If you block in work units submitted to GCD:
>
> - At best, you're using GCD inefficiently.
> - At worst, you're exposing yourself to the potential for 
>     starvation, and therefore (potentially) deadlocks.

Here's why: The OS has a per-process thread limit. Changing the per-process thread limit is not impossible, but in practical terms, doing so is rarely worth it. GCD has it's own queue width limit (number of threads it will use to service a concurrent queue). (Although the details are complicated, it's worth noting here that creating multiple concurrent queues will not, generally speaking, get around this limit.) By definition, GCD's limit is lower than the per-process thread limit. Furthermore, GCD's queue width limit is an undocumented implementation detail. Empirically, at the time of this writing, on OS X, I've observed that the limit appears to be 64. Because this limit is an undocumented implementation detail, you cannot count on knowing what it is. (It is also not possible to change it using public API.) Ideally speaking, your code should be written such that it would still execute to completion, albeit slowly, if GCD changed the queue width limit to be 1. (It could also be argued that the same should be true even if that one thread also happens to be the main thread, but that makes the task unnecessarily harder, and it seems safe to assume that there will always be at least one background thread, since it'd hardly be worth using GCD if there weren't.)

How would you do this? If you're blocking while waiting for I/O, you would want to consider transitioning your code to use the `dispatch_io` family of calls. For a quasi-busy wait situation (i.e. the original question), you could use `dispatch_after` to check back on something after a set amount of time. For other cases, dispatch timers or dispatch sources may be appropriate.

I'll be the first to admit that it is not always practical (let alone expedient) to completely avoid blocking in work units submitted to GCD. Furthermore, the combination of GCD and Objective-C block-syntax makes it very simple to write expressive, easy-to-read code for avoiding situations where you would block the UI thread by moving blocking/synchronous operations to a background thread. In terms of expediting development, this pattern is extremely helpful, and I use it all the time. That said, it's worth knowing that enqueuing a work unit with GCD that blocks consumes some amount of a finite resource (i.e. number of threads available) whose size you, pedantically speaking, can't know (because it's an undocumented implementation detail, and could change at any time) and, practically speaking, can't control (because you can't set/change GCD's queue width using public API.)

With respect to the original question: Busy-waiting (for example, by calling `sleep` or `usleep`) is one of the *most* avoidable, and *least* defensible ways to block in a work unit submitted to GCD. I will go further and make the bold statement that there is **always** a better, if less expeditious-to-develop, way to implement any operation that can be implemented by busy-waiting in a GCD work unit.

<sub>* I'm using "work unit" to refer to Objective-C blocks or function pointers/arguments submitted to GCD for execution to limit confusion with the work "blocking", by which I mean "doing something that results in your thread being suspended in the kernel".</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Using sleep with Grand Central Dispatch may be a bit of an issue because, GCD pools threads and so you are holding up a thread from being used by another job. GCD can of cause create more threads, but personnel I would avoid sleep in this situation, it would depend on the situation.

Comment: Making gdc queues sleep is like creating your own spinlock, just with more dependencies and problems!

Comment: What if I am must sleeping one queue that runs just this one task? I do not have many tasks running on this queue. I tried to suspend/resume the queue but it did not seem to work. I'd like to review a good example of making a GCD queue wait properly.

Comment: I can not think of any reasons why it is incorrect to sleep, it just seems a bit icky. Comparing it to spinlock is not really fair, you are not using any CPU cycle with sleep, and you are not preventing the CPU from flushing you code out of the cache, which is the other issue caused by spinlock.