# How to ensure two gcd queues run on separate threads?

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I'm in a situation where I want to ensure two queues end up executing on different threads. Ideally, I'd like to ensure they're serial queues. In particular, in the example below, if both queues run on the same thread, doStuff will be busy-waiting indefinitely. Am I going to have to move to explicit threading or can I salvage use of GCD here?

```
- (void)foo {
    self.responseQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.blah.response", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

    self.requestQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.blah.request", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

    dispatch_async(self.requestQueue, ^{
        [self doStuff];
    });
}

- (BOOL)doStuff {
    BOOL __block waiting = YES;

    self.responseBlock = ^{
        waiting = NO;
    };

    [self performRequest];

     while (waiting) {
         // realize could use dispatch_semaphore (busy waiting just to illustrate point).    
         sleep(1);
     }

     [self doStuffRequiringResponseCompletion];

     // I realize it would be sensible to 
     // 1) Not block in the above while loop.
     // 2) Call |doStuffRequiringResponseCompletion| after |receivedResponse|.
     // I don't want to do this.
}

// method called on arbitrary thread
- (void)receivedResponse {
    // stuff

    dispatch_async(self.responseQueue, self.responseBlock);
}
```

See also: [Is there any reason to not use sleep in a Grand Central Dispatch queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741048/is-there-any-reason-to-not-use-sleep-in-a-grand-central-dispatch-queue)?

Comment: It's not intuitive that performRequest magically calls receivedResponse. You should use a timeout in case performRequest fails. Why using two serial queues for request/response when it's a part of the same serial operation? Why the global responseBlock? Why async and block? GCD exists to avoid the complications of explicit threading. If you explain your use case you'll get suggestions for a better design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend using this solution because dispatch queues should not be abused for synchronization purposes but something like this is what I was after (however this is not guaranteed to not deadlock - deadlock could occur if the dispatch_sync block ran on a different thread than the one spun up by performSelectorInBackground):

```
- (void)foo {
    self.responseQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.blah.response", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

    self.requestQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.blah.request", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(dispatchRequest) withObject:nil]
}

- (void)dispatchRequest {
    dispatch_sync(self.requestQueue, ^{
        [self doStuff];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't ensure they run on different threads--the point of dispatch queues is that the OS manages the threads for you.  However, unless you are doing some highly specialized work that really, truly requires that you are running on specific threads, then the default behavior of your serial dispatch queues should work great for you.  If you really do need to ensure specific threads then you're back to using NSThread.

Comment: Any efforts taken to control which threads GCD blocks get executed upon, even if seemingly successful, are ultimately futile. Also, busy-waiting (i.e. calling `sleep()`) in a block submitted to GCD betrays a poor design. OP should rethink this using a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

A dispatch queue is not bound to a thread. If one of your dispatch items is blocking a thread, GCD will use or create other threads to process the other queues (and other items in this queue, if it is a concurrent queue).

There is an upper limit on the number of threads that GCD will create. If you have too many dispatch items sleeping like this then you may run into that limit and possibly deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid blocking the thread. Using your example, in your response block, after handling the response, you could enqueue another block back on com.blah.request to do whatever it is you were waiting to do.

Comment: I realize that's the sensible thing, but here I want to block requestQueue while responseQueue is executing.

Comment: then I wonder why you have two separate queues? Or have you considered targeting both the request and response queue to a single serial queue (a small hierarchy of 3)? Perhaps you can describe the use case more and I'll bet there is a solution more elegant than blocking a thread.

Comment: It's essentially a serial operation I'm undertaking so your original suggestion is best. I want a hackish solution to enforce two queues on separate threads though. (should clarify: I *don't* want one queue to block the other)

Comment: @Ehreh read this post about multiple readers and one writer.  I think it might do what you want without resorting to trying to force GCD to do something it wasn't designed to do.  http://www.objc.io/issue-2/low-level-concurrency-apis.html#multiple-readers-single-writer